# R: Variable Titles for Plotting

Tags: r, plot, title, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a function that plots a set of data using the basic plot command. It looks something like the following.

```
myfunction = function(input.data,title.str) {
    # commands to plot input.data using plot()
    title(main=title.str)
}

myfunction(object1,'show this title')
```

Basically I'm trying to pass a string as an argument and use it as the title of my plot. So far all the plotting works great and the problem is that I'm getting the following error.

Error in myfunction(object1,"show this title") : unused argument(s) ("show this title")

Comment: Are you sure that is all the code? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I modified the original function name without making the same change in the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have `object1` but this works for me:

```
myfunction = function(input.data, title.str) {
    plot(input.data)
    title(main = title.str)
}

object1 <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
myfunction(object1, "foo")
```

Comment: or even `plot(input.data, main=title.str)` in `myfunction()`

Comment: @Henry Indeed, but I presumed @crumbs357 had some reason for not using `main` in their plot call. They clearly were titling the plot separately via `title` but didn't show any plotting code so I had to guess/make some up.

Comment: fair enough.  Incidentally, you might remove the two > in your code as a kindness to those who try to copy and paste into R (I cannot as it involves fewer than 6 characters)

Comment: @Henry That should have been "Indeed, good point!". And thanks for pointing out the superfluous prompts, now removed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the version of myfunction that gives you that error is not the same as the one that you posted. The posted code works as expected for me.

You can check this by entering `myfunction` on the console (without brackets) and examining the function body that is printed.